# Is any PowerShell script convertible to a C# code?

Tags: c#, powershell

There's a very big PowerShell script which I'm responsible to work with.
I want to write a C# program to replace with this big script.

This script contains lots of jobs which are being executed on some remote machines.

**Question:** Does any PowerShell script have an equivalent code in C#?

Comment: Yes. If you find any cmdlets without direct equivalent you can wrap them in c# code

Comment: The answer is "it depends". There are many similarities between C# and PowerShell, and while they share the .NET library, the fact remains that one is a scripting language and the other is an object-oriented language. There's really no definitive answer to your question -- you're better off trying to convert it first and asking about a specific part that you get stuck on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Does any PowerShell script have an equivalent code in C#?"

No.

Any language can be CONVERTED to any other language, but what you are asking for is a language equivalency, i.e. sections of code or commands are EASILY converted from powershell to c#

A few lines of powershell code can do the same work as hundreds of lines of c#

Why do you want to convert the script?  if you are unfamiliar with powershell it is well worth learning...

Comment: Actually you've got the point exactly. I'm not unfamiliar with PowerShell but I feel it is not the right tool to create maintainable software. It's good for lots of administration tasks. In a programming language like C# we have lots of re-factoring tools, OO concepts and more.

Comment: I've used Powershell for many automation tasks but for me the code is easy to go back to and maintain - occasionally it will perform as well as c# - but its key benefit is the power of the language itself and the ability to access the entire .net framework.